# How do I call an Angular JS function from outside the controller via Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a project and using both Jquery and AngularJS. Jquery - primarily for the plugins already available. Angular - for the ease of working on forms and objects and DOM manipulation.

I have a plugin ( https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard) where custom events are defined like - onShow, onFinish, onNext etc. These events get triggered when the user does something.

How do I call an AngularJS function from one of these functions?

**Code From Plugin**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
            tabClass: 'nav nav-pills',
            onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {

               //I want to access the myFunction declared 
                //inside the AngularJS code and pass 'index' to it
            }
      });
    });
```

**AngularJS code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.myFunction = function(index) {
        // do something with index
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way for doing this would be retriving the scope of the controller from some element and then calling it's method like:

```
var myScope = angular.element($('#someElement')).scope();
myScope.doSomething(); // make sure you also invoke the $scope.$apply() to start the digest process.
```

But, think first, is this what you really want to do, I find this way bit hacky, also IMO mixing jQuery and Angular is not a good thing in the long run...

Comment: Yay! This works. Thanks so much. I know mixing them isn't the best thing to do. But i makes my life a lot simpler as I can have best of both worlds. Thanks again!

Comment: Proper way would be initialize plugin within a directive... scope is exposed in directive

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 controllers can be defined as standard Classes. If you define them this way it is easy to import and use them outside of angular as well.

```
class MainController {

  constructor(searchService) {
    this.title = 'Hello World';
  }

  myFunction () {
    // do things...
  } 

  someOtherFunction () {
    // do things...
  }

}
export { MainController }
```

in `app.js` (or whatever)

```
import { someFunction, someOtherFunction } from "web/static/js/MainController";
```

then you can access it with:

```
let result = someFunction();
```